# Inaccurate rotation with CABasicAnimation... doesn't match the correct angle

Tags: rotation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am developing a maps application. I draw an animated line in the map and then use an image (a ruler image) which should be draw just over the line. To draw the line I use a CABasicAnimation with path:

```
    -(void)lineaAnimation {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
        animation.duration = animDuration;
        animation.delegate=self;
        animation.repeatCount = 0;
        animation.autoreverses = NO;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        animation.fromValue = (id)inip;
        animation.toValue = (id)finp;
        animation.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.removedOnCompletion=NO;
        [shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
    }

    -(void)linea:(CGPoint)origen to:(CGPoint)destino animado:(BOOL)anim duracion:(float)durac inicio:(float)delay {
        inip    = CGPathCreateMutable();
        finp    = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGPathMoveToPoint(inip, nil, origen.x, origen.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(inip, nil, origen.x, origen.y);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(inip);

        CGPathMoveToPoint(finp, nil, origen.x, origen.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(finp, nil, destino.x, destino.y);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(finp);

        rootLayer   = [CALayer layer];
        rootLayer.frame = fondo.bounds;
        [fondo.layer addSublayer:rootLayer];

        shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        shapeLayer.path = inip;
        UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
        UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;
        shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
        [morrallaLayer addObject:shapeLayer];
        [rootLayer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
        animDuration=durac;
        [self performSelector:@selector(lineaAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
    }
```

Then I try to move the center of the rule to the point and rotate the ruler image using this code:

```
    delta=acos((destino.y-origen.y)/(destino.x-origen.x));
    giroIni=0.0;
    giroFin=delta;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    animation.fromValue= [NSNumber numberWithFloat:giroIni];
    animation.toValue= [NSNumber numberWithFloat:giroFin];
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.repeatCount = 0;
    animation.autoreverses = NO;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.duration = animDuration;
    animation.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion=NO;
    [ruleL addAnimation:animation forKey:@"giroAngulo"];
```

The problem is that the ruler borderline doesn't match the line draw, there are around a degree of difference depending on the final orientation... why?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ooooops... sorry for your time :(
I found the problem and.. as usual the error is not in the stars but in ourselves

I use the acos function when OBVIOUSLY I should use atan